# Reported speech with the word "before"

Tags: reported-speech

I have such a sentence:

> 'Who did you see at the club last night?' Tony asked me.

I need to transform it into reported speech using the word *before*. But wherever I put the word, it changes the meaning of the sentence. I've tried the following:

1. Tony asked me who I saw at the club before last night.
2. Tony asked me who I saw before the club last night.

Are there any other options which wouldn't change the meaning?

Comment: Yes - use _the night before_ instead of _last night_! The person reporting the speech may be speaking the next day or even later.

Comment: What ***is*** your intended meaning? Two possibilities that come to mind are (1) You're talking about the night before last night (i.e. - two nights ago), and (2) You're asking which people the addressee had seen ***on some earlier occasion*** (as well as last night).

Comment: @FumbleFingers the second case fits more.

Comment: Yet you describe what you're trying to achieve by saying you want to convert *'Who did you see at the club last night?' Tony asked me* into "reported speech". But looking at the actual words Tony spoke, he simply asked *who you saw* - he didn't mention anything about whether or not you'd seen any of those people *before* last night. Anyway, if that really ***is*** what you're trying to express, it's quite a lot of information to express in a single sentence. Tony would need to have asked something more like *"Who did you see at the club last night **that you hadn't seen before**?"*

Comment: ...but Tony probably wouldn't phrase his question like that. He'd more likely just ask *"Did you see anyone new at the club last night?"*, in which case the reported speech version would simply be *Tony asked me if I'd seen anyone new at the club last night*.